# Javascript: Broken letter shifting function

Tags: javascript, string, translation, alphabetical

Trying to write a simple function to take a string as input, then shift each character over once alphabetically. (a -> b) (f -> g) (z -> a). My function so far is broken. I'm sure there are better ways to go about this, but if someone would be willing to troubleshoot my function that would be awesome. :)

```
function translate(str) {
  var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k',
                'l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
  str.toLowerCase();
  var i = 0;
  var j;
  //edit: deleted str = ""

while (i < str.length) {
  for (j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
    if (str[i] == alphabet[alphabet.length - 1]) { //changed data type
        str += alphabet[0]
        j=0;
      } else if (str[i] == alphabet[j]) {
        str += alphabet[j+1]; //fixed this
        j=0;
      } else {
        i++; 
      }
    }
  }
  return str;
```

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [help])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `charCodeAt` and `fromCharCode` to realize your shifting. I might be a little bit more convienent:

```
function translate(str) {
    res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var ch = str.charCodeAt(i);

        //65 => A
        //90 => Z
        //97 => a
        //122 => z

        //if ch betweet A and Z or between a and z
        if ((ch >= 65 && ch <= 90) || (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122)) {
            //if z or Z transform to a or A respectively
            if (ch === 90 || ch === 122) ch -= 25;
            //else increase by one
            else ch += 1;
        }
        res.push(ch);
    }
    return = String.fromCharCode.apply(this, res);
}
```

Both methods use unicode representation of the string. Essentially, you transform the single characters into numbers, increase those numbers by one and transform it back to a letter. Here is a unicode table that shows the value of each letter: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is a little flawed. Just iterate through the string and use the `indexOf` method along with the modulo operator:

```
var index = alphabet.indexOf(char.toLowerCase());

if (index === -1) {
    // char isn't in the alphabet, so you should skip it
} else {
    var newChar = alphabet[(index + 1) % alphabet.length];
}
```

`(index + 1)` adds `1` to the index, which selects the next letter, and `% alphabet.length` makes it wrap around to the beginning in case of `z`.

Comment: would i set char = str.charAt(i)?

Comment: @JSNewb: Unless you want to modify your existing string, I would just push the new characters into an array (let's say `result`) and then return `result.join('')`, which joins together all of the letters into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
function translate(str) {
  var newStr = "";
  var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var currentLetter = str.substring(i, i+1);
    var newLetter = alphabet[(alphabet.indexOf(currentLetter.toLowerCase()) + 1) % alphabet.length]; 
    // preserve the case of the letter
    newStr += (currentLetter === currentLetter.toUpperCase()) ? newLetter.toUpperCase() : newLetter;
  }

  return newStr;
}
```

The general idea is to loop through each character, find its position in the `alphabet` array, and add its successor to the new string.

You'll have to add more logic if you need it to handle strings containing symbols, numbers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few problems here.

1. `var str = "";`. `str` is the variable you are sending as a parameter, so you reset it with this statement.
2. `if (str[i] == alphabet.length - 1)`. `str[i]` and `alphabet.length - 1` are not the same data type, so this statement is probably not doing what you think it should. Maybe you should have `alphabet[alphabet.length - 1]` instead.
3. `else if (str[i] == alphabet[j]) { str += alphabet[j]; //... }`. This would add the same letter onto your result string if you didn't reset `str` like in #1. You should have something like `alphabet[(j+1) % alphabet.size]` instead.

Also, you should use `charAt(i)` for getting characters in a string, not subscripts (`[]`), and you don't have to call `j=0` at the end of your `for` loops, since you already say `j=0` in the loop.